# Reverting/updating "FILE_DISPLAY" in Features

Tags: 7, features, media

My site is running Drupal v7.30 and Features v7.x-2.2. I can't revert or update `file_display` components in features. There are additional definitions under the Default column that appear to be define by the Media (7.x-2.0-alpha3) module in `hook_file_default_displays_alter()`. How do I go about properly keeping my features not in a perpetual `Overridden` state?

[image: Screenshot of Features File_Display diff]

Comment: This issue from Panopoly might be helpful ['file_display' components are always overridden (update Media / File Entity)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2159149).

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with media and the media modules.

There is some patches already that you could try

https://www.drupal.org/node/2104193